# How to identify memory leaks in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

How to check memory leaks in Android?
I tried using the Memory Analyzer tool in Eclipse, but out of the report it generated, I queried for a particular class, and I couldn't get anything out of it.

Also there isn't much documentation available on why this particular object could be the reason for a memory leak.

Can anyeone explain, possibly with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

Add to `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
   releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
 }
```

In `Application class`:

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    LeakCanary.install(this);
  }
}
```